# Parse push notification not working even though status 200

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am stuck with a weird issue. Am calling parse push api via rest call. The status shows 200. But my android device does not receive the notification (9 out of 10 times it does not receive the notification).

**Data sent from my server**

```
{"data":{"message":"dd","lastName":"Raman","alert":"New Message","notificationType":"MSG","from":134,"date":1422977063220,"firstName":"Mithun"},"where":{"deviceToken":{"$in":["MyDeviceToken"]},"deviceType":"android"}}
```

**My android class**

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //I put a break point here.. This never gets called
    }
}
```

**My Application Class**

```
public class TMP extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "ABC", "ABC");

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any one faced this issue ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. In theory, if successful, that endpoint should return a 201 (created) and not a 200. So, something's not right. Unfortunately, the response is "OK" with an empty body, which makes it tough to troubleshoot...

Comment: I have also noticed the following: 1) After the api call for push notification is made, if i go to the Parse Dashboard, it shows push status as succeeded and pushes sent as 1. But my device does not get the notification. 2) However if i turn the wifi off and back on again, i immediately receive all the notifications. Therafter everything works fine for sometime.